# Do any command line parameters pass when invoking program as myCopy file1.txt file2.txt file3.bin in C?

Tags: c, command-line, arguments

I'm specifically confused about the agrc and argv here. I know argc contains number of arguments with programs name being first and argv is the array of pointers that are strings.

However, in this case, will argv[argc] contain any command line parameters or not? Shouldn't argv[1] contain myCopy?

Comment: give it a try: write a program that prints out argc and all the items in argv.  that will help you see how this works.

Comment: arrays start at 0, so `argv[0]` contains the command name. `argv[argc]` should not be accessed as it's outside array bounds or maybe contains NULL, not sure now

Comment: Create a loop from `0` (don't forget array indexes are zero-based) to `argc - 1` (inclusive), and print all elements of `argv` with those indexes.

Comment: `argv[argc]` is equivalent to `array[arraylen]`, which you probably know is out of bounds (this is why `for` loops run `< length`).

Comment: @ggorlen The `argv` array is a special case, where `argv[argc]` is specified to always be a `NULL` pointer.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Nice to know